# How to get image from relative URL in C#, the image cannot be in the project

Tags: c#, xml, url, imagesource

I have a project where I'm loading relative image Uri's from an xml file.
I'm loading the image like this:

```
if (child.Name == "photo" &&
    child.Attributes["href"] != null &&
    File.Exists(child.Attributes["href"].Value))
{
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(child.Attributes["href"].Value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    images.Add(image);
}
```

Where the "child" object is an XmlNode which could looks like this

```
<photo name="info" href="Resources\Content\test.png"/>
```

During debug it seemd images is filled with actual images but when I want to see them in any way it shows nothing.
Weird thing is when I include the images in my project it does work, I however dont want to do that since my point for using an xml file is so that it would be lost since you'd have to rebuild the program anyway after a change.

Comment: try prefixing ~\ in your path. It should take relative from your application's directory

Comment: Doesnt seem to work, if I add that part the File.Exists wont return true anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the perfect solution but its works nonetheless, I'm converting the relative Uri's to absolute ones like this

```
if (child.Name == "photo" &&
    child.Attributes["href"] != null &&
    File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + child.Attributes["href"].Value))
{
    Image image = new Image();
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Environment.CurrentDirectory + child.Attributes["href"].Value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    images.Add(image);
}
```

Only had to change all the Uri's in the xml to have a leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm can be this simple current folder problem. VS check resources under project/Resources/Content/ folder and program check resources under project/bin/Debug/Resources/Content/ folder.

Comment: The resources folder is copied to the debug folder, the strange part is, I use File.Exists to see if it exists, which returns true.